# Order a variable to display from the highest to lowest value

Tags: php

my code below will echo the position of the user if the number($nm) fall
between the range so let say i have $nm = (10,4,3,3,1) respectively the position will be (staff,staff,staff,marketer,staff) instead of (marketer,staff,staff,staff,staff) how can i arrange so that marketer come first (marketer,staff,staff,staff,staff).

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT username,num FROM user ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die('query error');
while( $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$um = $line[username];
$nm = $line[num];

echo "name:$um";

if($nm <= 50){
echo "Position: president";
}else if($nm <= 40){
echo "Position: vice";
}else if($nm <= 30){
echo "Position: manager";
}else if($nm <= 20){
echo "Position: marketer";
}else if($nm <= 10){
echo "Position: staff";
}
```

Comment: Your code will print `president` for every number (unless it's greater than 50).

Comment: How does `(10,4,3,3,1)` become `(staff,staff,staff,marketer,staff)` (or `(marketer,staff,staff,staff,staff)`), all the numbers are less than or equal to 10?

Answer (score 0):

```
while( $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $ums[] = $line[username];
    $nms[] = $line[num];
}

usort($nms);

foreach ($nms as $nm){
   if($nm <=  50){
      echo "Position: president";
   }else if($nm <= 40){
      echo "Position: vice";
   }else if($nm <= 30){
      echo "Position: manager";
   }else if($nm <= 20){
      echo "Position: marketer";
   }else if($nm <= 10){
      echo "Position: staff";
   }
}
```

Comment: `usort` needs a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) would solve your problem

but isnt your if/else if wrong ?

shouldnt it be ?

```
if($nm <= 10){
  echo "Position: staff";
} else if($nm <= 20){
  echo "Position: marketer";
} else if($nm <= 30){
  echo "Position: manager";
} else if($nm <= 40){
  echo "Position: vice";
} else if($nm <=  50){
  echo "Position: president";
}
```